# Changes not saved when using paragraph in paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, 9

The project is in Drupal 9.0.2

Recovery steps:

- I created a content type,
- Inside it there is an entity reference field of paragraph.
- Inside this paragraph there is an entity reference field which is also a paragraph.
- For the first time when I save the contents of the fields of the inner paragraph the contents are saved in DB,
- But in a second time update onwards the field changes are not saved.
- There is no any error on the screen and without any error in the LOG files.

Can someone help me understand where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  This sounds like a bug but to tell anything with a little bit more certainty we need to know the exact steps to reproduce the issue. In what environment is your D9 running? How you've set it up and what types of paragraphs to we need to create to run into this issue? Please edit your question for clarification. Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what you're doing wrong is thinking someone here can answer your question when you have no errors and we don't have access to your site. What you need to do is try to replicate the issue on a fresh D9 install with Paragraphs as the only contrib module installed. If you can replicate the issue then you need to look at the modules [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/paragraphs?categories=All) and see if anyone has created an issue about it and if not, create the issue with all the steps to reproduce.

Comment: If you can't replicate the issue, then some custom or contrib module is causing the issue. You could try debugging the issue by using Xdebug or some other debugging tool to see what happens after the submit handler is called.